# RAID Controller Acting Weird with a New Hard Drive

Tags: raid, raid5, controller, failed

(Not sure on the model at the moment will update once I know)

So we had a a RAID 5 that had two hard drives fail at the same time.

Positions 0 and and 1 are labeled as "online".
Positions 2 and 3 are labeled as "failed".

We had a backup drive (of course) and put it in position 2. The drive is still telling us as position 2 as "failed". Is this usual behavior? Is won't let us rebuild of course since we lost two drives.

(To make sure the controller wasn't just the thing that died, we tried switching the drives around. Switched 0 and 2 positions' cords. 0 went to failed while 2 went to online. The problems followed the drives)

What should we do?

EDIT:
Put in the new drive and now on boot it's saying
"unresolved configuration mismatch between disk(s) and NVRAM on the adapter"
No idea what that means. xD

Comment: Update:
Forced the RAID to recognize the 3rd hard drive in the array and while it warned me that if the drive did not contain data or was corrupted it could corrupt the entire RAID, all the data was there and is currently backing up to tape! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to the fact that the new drive doesn't contain the signature/metadata for the raid volume which is failed.  I would try removing the failed raid volume from the controller and create a new volume with the new drive in place.

Comment: New error/information
"unresolved configuration mismatch between disk(s) and NVRAM on the adapter"

Comment: I think this means that the configuration in the controller's bios doesn't match the metadata and signatures it's seeing on the disks.

Comment: Does this mean there's a good chance our data is still ok? If so what should we do?

Comment: We rebooted again and got the same message. Rebooted yet again and did *not* get that message. Very odd!

Comment: If you lost two drives in a RAID5 array your best option is to throw away the RAID volume and create a new one and restore from a recent backup.  If you don't have any backups and need that data back be very careful about what you do.  If you don't know what you're doing you can do more damage to your data reducing that ability to ever recover it.  A data recovery firm is probably the best course of action.  But better prepare yourself for a large bill.